# How to convert AutoCAD file to Visio?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-visio, autocad

How to convert .dwg format files in AutoCAD to Visio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To Convert DWG to VSD**

> - Open up Visio on your
>     computer.
> - Click "File" and select "Open" from the menu. This will bring up the open
>     file dialog box.
> - Use the drop down menu in the open file dialog box to select AutoCAD
>     files as the file type that you wish
>     to open. This will enable you to open
>     AutoCAD DWG and DXF files in Visio.
>     Select the DWG file that you want to
>     convert and click "Open."
> - Verify that the open file is the one that you want to convert. Use your
>     mouse to right click on the DWG file
>     on your screen. When you do this, a
>     menu will appear and you will need to
>     point your mouse on "CAD Drawing
>     Object" to get more options. Select
>     "Convert."
> - Select the layers of the DWG file that you want to convert in the CAD
>     conversion screen that has appeared.
>     Click "OK" when you are done and the
>     file will convert for you.

Answer taken from [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5135729_convert-dwg-vsd.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the info on Microsoft support site [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/import-or-insert-autocad-drawings-pictures-and-clip-art-HP001231453.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/convert-an-autocad-dwg-or-dxf-file-into-visio-format-HP001207715.aspx), you can simply import dwg file to start a new Visio drawing.